# Find "Missing" Integer in a Java Array

Tags: java, arrays, numbers

Given an array `A[]` of length `n`, find a "missing" number `k` such that:

- `k` is not in `A`
- `0<=k<=n`

I've seen similar questions asked where the `A[]` contains numbers `1` to `n` with one number missing, but in this question, `A[]` can contain any numbers. I need a solution in `O(n)` time. For example,

```
A = {1,2,3} -> 0
A = {0,1,2} -> 3
A = {2,7,4,1,6,0,5,-3} -> 3,8
```

I've gotten as far as checking if `0` or `n` are in the array, and if not, return 0 or n, but I cannot seem to think of any other solution. This problem seems considerably more difficult given the fact that `A` can contain any numbers and not necessarily numbers 1 to n or something like that.

Comment: Note: I know that only checking if 0 or n are not in the array will not give an accurate solution to most arrays.

Comment: If `A[]` can contain ***any*** numbers, then what defines `n`. Is it the largest value in `A`? If so, what if the "missing" number is greater than the largest number? This question is underspecified.

Comment: @JimGarrison `array A[] of length n`, so `n = A.length`, that's okay.

Comment: Question is answered. Thank you all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Linearly iterate over the array and "cross out" every number you encounter. Then iterate of that listed of crossed out numbers again and see which one is missing.

```
 public static int getMissingNumber(int[] A) 
 {  
    int n = A.length;  
    boolean[] numbersUsed = new boolean[n + 1]; //Because the definition says 0 <= k <= n, so k = n is also possible.

    for(int k = 0; k < n; k++) 
    {
        if(A[k] <= n && A[k] >= 0) //No negative numbers!
           numbersUsed[A[k]] = true;
    }

    for(int k = 0; k <= n; k++) 
    {
       if(numbersUsed[k] == false) 
          return k;
    } 
    return -1; //nothing found
 }
```

Complexity is 2*n because of the two `for` loops, giving overall complexity `O(n)`.

Comment: Third example indicates to return a list of all missing numbers, not just the first one.

Comment: Indeed, OP can return a `List<int>` by iterating over all non-crossed out entries in the array. But the initial problem said to find a single number ("find a "missing" number k such that.."). I leave it to OP to edit the code :).

Comment: Thank you very much. I feel dumb for not thinking of this.

Answer (score 1):

Simple approach:

- initialize a set with all the values you need. (In your case number 0 to n)
- iterate over your arry and remove the number from the set
- at the end the set is giving you the missing entries.

Comment: Good simple explanation. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that exactly one number is missing, there is a simple solution using xor.

```
static int missing(int[] arr) {
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        result ^= (i + 1) ^ arr[i];
    return result;
}
```

If there may be more than one number missing you can return a `Set` like this:

```
static Set<Integer> missing(int[] arr) {
    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
    for (int i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++)
        set.add(i);
    for (int a : arr)
        set.remove(a);
    return set;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what   result ^= (i + 1) ^ arr[i];   does?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that utilizes one loop. That's if we choose to ignore what Arrays.sort does

```
import java.util.Arrays;
class Solution {
    public int solution(int[] A) {
        Arrays.sort(A);     
        int min = 1; 

        for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++){
            if(A[i]== min){
                min++;
            }
        }   
        min = ( min <= 0 ) ? 1:min;
        return min;    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Missing{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      int arr[]={1,2,4,5,6,7,9};
      System.out.println(missingNumberArray(arr));
       }
    public static int missingNumberArray(int [] a) {
        int result=0;
        for(int i=0;i<a.length-1;i++){
            if(a[i+1]-a[i]!=1){
                result=a[i]+1;
            }
         }
        return result;
      }
    }

    //output:missing element is:3
    // missing element is:8
```

Comment: It is mainly used  for finding only positive element .